# How to separate javascript libraries and calls in the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to get the hang of the whole asset pipeline thing, and read the guide and several tutorials about them. But one thing that doesn't become quite clear is wether I should view my javascript asset files as a library or a place to put code that is actually run i.e. $(document).ready. Because by default all the javascript files are included, and it would be weird to have several $(document).ready's in there, not to mention that you don't want the $(document).ready function for every page to be run in the first place. What would be the way to go at this? Use my asset files as a library and put actual calls in my views (ugly)? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What's forcing you to use document ready for all your js files? If you had a pre Rails 3.1 js file that wasn't using document ready then it shouldn't need document ready in Rails 3.1. Also, it isn't weird to have several document ready calls, they're simply binding more code to it.

Comment: document.ready was just an example. The main question is how I should separate the code that is actually run from function definitions or a library. I don't want the javascript for my foocontroller to run when I'm on a page rendered by my barcontroller. So, basically I don't mind to have my foo functions available when I'm on my barcontroller page, but I don't want any initialization code from it to be run.

Comment: How were you accomplishing this before Rails 3.1? Were you using supplying different arguments to `javascript_include_tag` on a per controller/action basis?

Comment: I would just use a javascript_include_tag in my application.html.erb that would include my library functions. Then I would use an extra javascript include tag to include the controller specific init javascript file that would do bindings etc. But now everything is already included by default, so I'm wondering what the best way to go at this is.

Comment: I don't know how many combinations of js you had, but it's probably safe to assume that the benefits of js concatenation/minification/md5 hashed filenames in Rails 3.1 far outweigh the benefits of only running your various sets of js initialization code when they're absolutely needed. If there are no conflicts then you should just let the initialization code run on every page.

Comment: Well, the problem is that you don't want to do something like $('#foo') in a page where there is nothing with the id foo, since you will get errors etc. And it doesn't seem natural to build checks for these kind of things in all of your initialization functions.

Comment: What kind of things are you trying to do with the page specific elements? Basic jquery functions will just return null or an empty array for non-existent selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely don't want a certain piece of initialization code to be run unless the current page is a specific controller/action, then you can try adding an empty element on the page with an id built from that info like "posts_index" using these two helpers:

`"#{controller_name}_#{action_name}"`

Then in your javascript you can wrap the code inside an if statement that checks for the existence of an element with the appropriate id.

edit: Here's an example of the js partial that I mentioned in the comments.

**`show.html.haml`**

`= render 'map'`

**`map.html.erb`** (I normally use haml but it's easier to write js in erb)

```
<script src='http://www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  ...
</script>
```

It's probably not as clean as it could be and it doesn't get the benefits of being part of the asset pipeline but I don't mind because it's only something that gets included on a specific page.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it seems to me that I'm missing something. What is the normal way to go about this. Executing javascript in the views maybe?, But that isn't really unobtrusive.

Comment: I need more info about what would cause a conflict from including all the javascript. Is it a specific function that fails because an element isn't on the page? I have some projects where I put code for google visualizations into partials (erb) and render them on the appropriate pages instead of putting them into the assets directory. Is that closer to what you're talking about?

Comment: That is what I'm talking about. I just want to make a distinction between javascript that is actually run and javascript libraries. i.e. including jquery doesn't actually run anything on my page, so I don't mind including it on every page. But for example a document.ready call will possibly change my page and therefore I want it only to be run when there is need for. And in the asset pipeline I don't see this distinction, it includes everything regardless of wether it is a library or code that needs to be run. I was checking if it can be done with something like yield :javascript.

Comment: Could you explain how you set it up with partials? (Didn't fit in my previous comment).

Comment: I guess I just need something more specific. Can you include a real example of your page-specific javascript from one page having an adverse effect when included on another page?

Comment: Hmm, I could give you an example, but I'm basically not trying to deal with a specific problem, but rather trying to figure out how to do a certain thing with the rails 3.1 asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I too ran into this issue. In a large project you can have somebody put code into document ready to, for example, add a click function to each **li** within a **div** with class **container**.

Now we could all argue that the above code would be too generic and of course may affect **li** tags in other parts of the application, but the bigger the project, the more likely it is that you will run into a conflict like this leading to unexpected behaviour.

I for one am uncomfortable with a whole bunch of document ready functions running for each and every page loaded. My solution is not necessarily the perfect one, but it's one that I have taken up and will share with you.

In the body tag of each page I add data elements signifying the controller and the action. I then have one document ready script that looks for a class named after the controller with the name Ready appended e.g. HomeReady. It will then call a method on this class (presuming it exists) named after the action. So in your asset coffee file you could write:

```
class @HomeReady
  @index: ->
    alert("Hello")
  @show: ->
    alert("Goodbye")
```

This allows control right down to the action level. When I came across your question I decided to package this solution into a gem as I have already used it in several projects. You can find it at: https://github.com/intrica/rails_document_ready

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it seems like a decent enough solution.